# What's the lightest and simplest solution for booting from BIOS?

Tags: linux, boot-loader, bios

I have a machine that only has BIOS and I don't want to use things like GRUB, since I only need to boot the only one kernel. Lightweight distros do that kind of thing, right? Like tiny core... amazing thing!

Comment: @K7AAY I specificly said, that it has ONLY BIOS. I'm perfectly aware of efistub

Comment: Thank you for the reinforcement. No, no method known, sorry.

Comment: If your kernel supports, write it directly to disk, not as file in filesystem, I also believe you're perfectly aware of BIOS boot sequence.

Comment: Without UEFI firmware, you will need a boot loader in any case. The Linux kernel does not provide a mechanism to start the kernel directly from the old BIOS firmware. There are a few alternatives to GRUB, like [Syslinux](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Syslinux_Project) and LILO. But if it's the the menu GRUB displays at boot that disturbs you, you can configure GRUB to not display it.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 what? what do you mean by 'writing directly to disk'? And what does it have to do with the boot sequence?

Comment: @JohanMyreen Doesn't linux kernel contains bootstrap code? Write kernel to header of the bootable partition then it will work, although I don't know how to use initramfs in such case or pass kernel arguments, but at least old version of kernel can work like this?

Comment: The Linux kernel did contain code to boot directly from a floppy disk. This was the way Linux was booted back in the day when the kernel didn't even support hard drives. You had one "boot" disk to start the kernel, and were prompted to insert the "root" disk at some point. I don't think that code works anymore, and it was just for floppy disks, anyway.